# Using continue statement in catch block

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreach, catch-block

I have a `foreach` loop that is looping through an entity framework result. Each result is being passed through a function. So to catch any errors I have a `try/catch` block setup.

Something like this:

```
foreach (var resetReq in query)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Attemtping password reset for: " + resetReq.uname);
        if (adTools.resetPassword(resetReq.uname, resetReq.agentUCID))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Password reset for: " + resetReq.uname);
            using (var updateDB = new resetDB())
            {
                Request r = updateDB.Requests.First(x => x.id == resetReq.id);
                r.reqCompletedDate = DateTime.Now;
                r.completed = 1;

                updateDB.SaveChanges();

                Console.WriteLine("Reset record for: " + resetReq.uname + 
                                  " updated successfully to reflect completion.");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        mailFunctions mailFunc = new mailFunctions();
        mailFunc.sendMail(ex);
        continue;
    }
}
```

My question is, will the `continue` statement in my catch block function properly? 
Meaning once the exception is thrown and my mail function is fired off, will it continue to loop?

Comment: yes it will function properly

Comment: Why don't you execute the code and let us know?
I think you don't need the continue at all.

Comment: In this case continue is redundant. `continue` makes no difference here. Code will behave exactly same irrespective of the continue statement.

Comment: This is a great example of a question that should be answered with a debugger instead of StackOverflow

Comment: Thanks for the input...I asked here because it didn't appear to be working and also because I wanted to know if it would even be necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `continue` will work.

However, it is redundant. You don't need the `continue` at all, since there is no code after the `catch` block, that needs to be skipped due to any exception being caught.